# Is it allowed and safe to recur the class new method (initialize) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, recursion, new-operator

I am new to object orientation programming/modelling and I have been using Ruby to program some planar graph algoritms. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
class Twin

  def initialize(name1,name2)
  ## creates two twin brothers and "returns" one of them
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def brother
    @brother
  end

end
```

I found no way to create the two twins in initialize in one shot except by recurring as it follows:

```
  def initialize(name1,name2)
    if @@flag.nil?
      @@flag = self
      @mybrother = Twin.new(name1,name2)
      @name = name1
    else
      @mybrother = @@flag
      @@flag = nil
      @name = name2
    end
  end
```

Am I allowed to use recursion in initialize method? I implemented this method and it seems to work. But I am unsure if it is dependent of the interpreter version.

I know I could write a class Person and a second class Twin to create and join them in pairs. But it seems an artificial modelling to me. I am trying to mimic the data structure I wrote in C using records some years ago.

---

EDIT: After digging a lot, based on the suggestion of @iamnotmaynard, I rewrote my code the following way:

```
class Twin

  def self.generate_twins(name1,name2)
    t1 = Twin.allocate
    t2 = Twin.allocate
    t1.instance_variable_set(:@name, name1)
    t1.instance_variable_set(:@brother, t2)
    t2.instance_variable_set(:@name, name2)
    t2.instance_variable_set(:@brother, t1)
    t1
  end

  def initialize
    raise "Use generate_twins to create twins"
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def brother
    @brother
  end

end
```

This code express what I was looking for without the recursion of initialize. Thank you all for your answers and comments that helped me to find it.

Comment: Rather than doing it in `initialize`, create a class method (something like `generate_twins`), which can create the two instances of `Twin` and return one (or both).

Comment: This seems to be a better solution. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class method to create the two twins. I would not use the initializer like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having seperate classes for this.

I'm not sure what the `twins` are consisted of, but you could create a class `Single`, which would hold the methods relevant to the single, and then another class "Twin" that you would pass in two `Single`s to.

Example

```
Class Single 
    def initialize(..)
        #Initialize the single object here
    end
    #include any methods relevant to the single object
end

Class Twin
    def initialize(single1, single2)
        #store the singles in the class
    end
    #Put methods that use both singles here
end
```